# Given a vector and angle find new vector

Tags: vector-spaces

Given a vector and an angle, how can i find an vector that the angle between the two vector is exactly the given angle?

Edit:

We are in the n-dimensional space and the new vector has a fixed given length.

Comment: Unless $n=2$, there exist infinitely many vectors that satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @5xum is it possible to describe all vectors through linear combinations of finite many vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in $\mathbb R^2$ take the rotation matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $\theta$ is your angle and multiply it with your vector.

For a vector $v\in\mathbb R^n$ with $n>2$ you should first decide in which plain you want to apply the rotation. Find an orthonormal basis $(b_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $b_1$ and $b_2$ span your rotation plain and $v\in\operatorname{span}(b_1,b_2)$. Now you can translate the rotation from above into that plain. Actually you don't have to care about $b_i$ for $i>2$ since nothing will change there.

Comment: we are in the n-dimensional space

Comment: @testy See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Find another vector that is not linearly dependent on the first (should be easy if you have more than one dimension), then you use that to construct a normal vector and last you combine the first and the normal vector to construct your final vector.

Let's say your original vector is $u$ and then select one of the basis vectors $e_j$ (you may have to select carefully if $u$ is parallel to some of the axes). Now $v = e_j - (e_j\cdot u)u/u^2$ is perpendicular to $u$:

$v\cdot u = e_j\cdot u - (e_j\cdot u)u^2/u^2 = 0$

Then we just combine $u$ and $v$:

$w = u\cos(\alpha) + v\sin(\alpha)$

In the special case where there is two dimensions one could immediately select $v$ as $(-u_y, u_x)$ resulting in just applying a rotation matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \\
\end{bmatrix}$$